# How to calculate bitmap size?

Tags: c++, winapi, math, bitmap

Started working on screen capturing software specifically targeted for Windows. While looking through an example on MSDN for [Capturing an Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402(v=vs.85).aspx) I found myself a bit confused.

Keep in mind when I refer to the size of the bitmap that does not include headers and so forth associated with an actual file. I'm talking about raw pixel data. I would have thought that the formula should be `(width*height)*bits-per-pixel`. However, according to the example this is the proper way to calculate the size:

```
DWORD dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;
```

and or: `((width*bits-per-pixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * height`

I don't understand why there's the extra calculations involving `31`, `32` and `4`. Perhaps padding? I'm not sure but any explanations would be quite appreciated. I've already tried Googling and didn't find any particularly helpful results.

Comment: There obviously must be padding, otherwise how could most things be stored in byte or word addressable memory?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38241706/62576) provides part of the information you're after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bits representing the bitmap pixels are packed in rows. The size of each row is rounded up to a multiple of 4 bytes (a 32-bit DWORD) by padding.

(bits_per_row + 31)/32 * 4 ensures the round up to the next multiple of 32 bits. The answer is in bytes, rather than bits hence *4 rather than *32.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually had begun looking at that exact wikipedia article earlier but didn't come across the part talking about this particular equation till I searched for "padding".

Answer (score 4):

Under [Bitmap Header Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183386.aspx) you'll find the following:

> The scan lines are **DWORD** aligned [...]. They must be padded for scan line widths, in bytes, that are not evenly divisible by four [...]. For example, a 10- by 10-pixel 24-bpp bitmap will have two padding bytes at the end of each scan line.

The formula

```
((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4
```

establishes `DWORD`-alignment (in bytes). The trailing `* 4` is really the result of `* 32 / 8`, where the multiplication with 32 produces a value that's a multiple of 32 (in bits), and the division by 8 translates it back to bytes.

Although this does produce the desired result, I prefer a different implementation. A `DWORD` is 32 bits, i.e. a power of 2. Rounding up to a power of 2 can be implemented using the following formula:

```
(value + ((1 << n) - 1)) & ~((1 << n) - 1)
```

Adding `(1 << n) - 1` adjusts the initial value to go past the next *n*-th power of 2 (unless it already is an *n*-th power of 2). `(1 << n) - 1` evaluates to a value, where the *n* least significant bits are set, `~((1 << n) - 1)` negates that, i.e. all bits but the *n* least significant bits are set. This serves as a mask to remove the *n* least significant bits of the adjusted initial value.

Applied to this specific case, where a `DWORD` is 32 bits, i.e. *n* is 5, and `(1 << n) - 1` evaluates to 31. *value* is the raw scanline width in bits:

```
auto raw_scanline_width_in_bits{ bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount };
auto aligned_scanline_width_in_bits{ (raw_scanline_width_in_bits + 31) & ~31 };
auto aligned_scanline_width_in_bytes{ raw_scanline_width_in_bits / 8 };
```

This produces the same results, but provides a different perspective, that may be more accessible to some.