# Taking screenshot using bmp file in c?

Tags: c, bmp

I'm trying to create a 3D Game using c.

when adding the flag '--save'
The game takes a screenshot and saves it.

so to do this (taking a screenshot from the game).
I have to use **BMP file**, so I have to make it using c.

The code:

```
#include "../includes/cub3d.h"

t_screenshot        *ft_init_shot(t_mlx *mlx)
{
    t_screenshot    *takeshot;

    takeshot = malloc(1 * sizeof(t_screenshot));
    takeshot->width = w;
    takeshot->height = h;
    takeshot->bitcount = 24;
    takeshot->width_in_bytes = ((takeshot->width * takeshot->bitcount + 31) / 32) * 4;
    takeshot->imagesize = takeshot->width_in_bytes * takeshot->height;
    takeshot->filesize = 54 + takeshot->imagesize;
    return (takeshot);
}

unsigned char       *ft_bitheader(t_mlx *mlx)
{
    unsigned char    *header;
    uint32_t bisize;
    uint32_t bfoffbits;
    uint16_t biplanes;
    
    header =(unsigned char *)malloc(54 * sizeof(char));
    bisize = 40;
    bfoffbits = 54;
    biplanes = 1;
    memcpy(header, "BM", 2);
    memcpy(header + 2 , &mlx->shot->filesize, 4);
    memcpy(header + 10, &bfoffbits, 4);
    memcpy(header + 14, &bisize, 4);
    memcpy(header + 18, &mlx->shot->width, 4);
    memcpy(header + 22, &mlx->shot->height, 4);
    memcpy(header + 26, &biplanes, 2);
    memcpy(header + 28, &mlx->shot->bitcount, 2);
    memcpy(header + 34, &mlx->shot->imagesize, 4);
    return (header);
}

void                screen_shot(t_mlx *mlx)
{
    ft_move(mlx);
    ft_update(mlx, YES);
    mlx->shot = ft_init_shot(mlx);
    mlx->shot->header = ft_bitheader(mlx);
    screno(mlx);
}
 
void                screno(t_mlx *mlx)
{
    int x ;
    int y ;
    int row;
    int col;

    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    row = mlx->shot->height - 1;
    col = 0;
    unsigned char* buf = malloc(mlx->shot->imagesize);
    while (row >= 0)
    {
        y = 0;
        col = 0;
        while (col < mlx->shot->width)
        {
            int red = (mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] >> 16) & 0xFF;
            int green = (mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] >> 8) & 0xFF;
            int blue = mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] & 0xFF;
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 0] = blue;
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 1] = green;
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 2] = red;
            col++;
            y++;
        }
        row--;
        x++;
    }
    ft_printf("Taking ScreenShoot....\n");
    FILE *image = fopen("screenshot.bmp", "wb");
    ft_printf("ScreenShot Has been saved under The name 'screenshot.bmp']\n");
    fwrite(mlx->shot->header, 1, 54, image);
    fwrite((char*)buf, 1, mlx->shot->imagesize, image);
    fclose(image);
    free(buf);
}
```

The problem is when I compiling This code the image appear some time and some time give me this error:

[image: screenshot to see the error I got]

Thank You for Your help.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, this program leaks memory all over the place. Calling free() for each allocated chunk might in itself reveal heap corruption, which in turn can be caused by array-out-of-bounds, invalid pointers etc etc.

Comment: The file format is probably wrong, google _bmp file format_

Comment: Where is `mlx` allocated?

Comment: Regarding bmp format, does it assume/require little endian? Because some data here is calculated using endianess-independant code such as `int red = (mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] >> 16) & 0xFF;`, while other data is hardcoded little endian such as `memcpy(header + 10, &bfoffbits, 4);`

Comment: Have you checked the header of the created file for proper values?

Comment: `y` and `col` always have same value. No need to use 2 variables. The inner loop could simply be `for (col=0; col < mlx->shot->width; col++)` without any variable `y`. Outer loop could also be more readable by using a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank You all for Your help. This is The answer:
[I found it on This question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50090500/create-simple-bitmap-in-c-without-external-libraries?fbclid=IwAR2m4yl07RTzjTyXq16InJgCqnmtUXxV0BavCmIIHgrlBbql2eqFZwhUESQ)